# Recent Macroeconomics dataset of all countries in the World

Tags: data-request, economics, county

I need a dataset that contains recent macroeconomics attributes for countries. I have tried to make my own by joining Wikipedia tables on GDP, GDP per capita, population, poverty, imports, exports, life expectancy, illiteracy rate, external debt, number of internet users etc. However, the dataset is not very consistent with regards to the sources and timestamp. It would be great to have at least somehow consistent dataset including but not limited to the above mentioned attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

International organisations provide this kind of data. As you want to cover the whole World, have a look at organisations with the same geographical scope:

The World Bank has [a database that covers a wide range of topics](http://data.worldbank.org).

If you are more focussed on economic indicators, you can also have a look at the [World Economic Outlook Database of the International Monetary Fund (IMF)](http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2015/01/weodata/index.aspx).

Both sites allow you to view the data online as well as to download it further uses.

The United Nations Statistics Division also has [a couple of databases on various topics](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/databases.htm).

Comment: WEO page to get a downloadable data file: http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2015/01/weodata/weoselgr.aspx. Open with Excel then save as an XLS file or whatever you want. Your browser might choke for 1-2 minutes if there is a lot of data, just leave the browser alone, it will come back. You can also specify countries, data points, and a range of dates. Future dates will be estimates. I prefer grouping by subject then country.

Answer (score 3):

About import and export: [TradeMap](http://www.trademap.org/Index.aspx), a Swiss statistical tool providing indicators on:

- Export performance
- International demand
- Alternative markets
- Competitive markets

They also have a directory of importing and exporting companies of more than 200 countries more than 5000 products.

Another economic indicator is the [World Trade Organization Database](http://stat.wto.org/CountryProfile/WSDBCountryPFReporter.aspx?Language=E), on which you are available to make comparisons between their members states, with full economic information.